How to format space in between bullet points in Marketing Cloud (No experience coding)
I don't have any experience coding and I don't know HTML, but I have a bulleted list in a Marketing Cloud email and I'd like to add some space in between the bullets. Ideally, someone can tell me exactly what I need to type to achieve this. The block code is below:



You might want to try adding some padding to the top and bottom of the li tag. For example:
<ul>
<li style="padding: 5px 0;">
  <span style="font-size:15px;">What flour shoppers want, depending on where they shop</span>
</li>
<li style="padding: 5px 0;">
  <span style="font-size:15px;">The second line...</span>
</li>
</ul>

And an important thing is if you want to do it yourself, you would need to learn about it. W3schools has great sources that can help you learn the basics of HTML and CSS.
